# Not getting any results for Ray Rllib in Google colab even if memory is allocated

Tags: google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I am trying follow this tutorial
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJYH.png): https://github.com/anyscale/academy/blob/main/ray-rllib/02-Introduction-to-RLlib.ipynb. But when I am implementing it on Google colab, I am not getting any results. It is only showing that the trial pending and memory is allocated

```
from ray import tune
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer, DEFAULT_CONFIG

import ray
info = ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)
tune.run(PPOTrainer, 
        config={"env": "CartPole-v1"},
        stop={"training_iteration": 20},
        local_dir = "/content/ppo",
        checkpoint_at_end=True,
        verbose=2            # 2 for INFO; change to 1 or 0 to reduce the output.
        )
```

After running this instance, I am getting

[image]

Am I getting anything wrong here? Why is it not running even if ray is initialised

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the argument `num_cpus=12` in `ray.init()` solved the issue.